# MOTD displaying content of /etc/motd generated at boot / previous login

Tags: server, ssh, login, motd

I have an Ubuntu server running at sandbox.plushu.org - if you add your key at http://enter.sandbox.plushu.org, you can connect to the server as root@sandbox.plushu.org. You can reset the server by pressing the reset button on http://reset-sandbox.plushu.org.

I have a custom time-sensitive MOTD on this server. The problem that I'm seeing is that this MOTD, when regenerated (via /etc/update-motd/*) at login, is not *displayed* until the *next* login. The first time you log in, you will see the MOTD as generated at boot: the next time you log in, you will see the MOTD as generated the *last* time you logged in.

What is causing this behavior? How can it be fixed so that, on logging in, the MOTD is generated, *then* displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is configured in **/etc/pam.d/sshd**:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
```

Try to remove "**noupdate**" keyword.

As described in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pam_motd.8.html - it means..

> *Don't run the scripts in /etc/update-motd.d to refresh the motd file.*

Comment: Holy cow, that fixed it! What a bizarre and counter-intuitive option. Why is this set out of the box when the default MOTD contains things like system stats?

Comment: This appears to be a problem as of 2015-nov-7 on DigitalOcean hosting. I used this technique to fix it.